# Git permission error with a twist

Tags: windows-10, permissions, git, git-for-windows

I just booted my Windows 10 machine for the first time in two or three months and updated a game whose versions I'm keeping in a git repo. There was a patch to the game, so I tried to stage the changes and got this error:

> error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects

I haven't changed anything since it worked a few months ago. `ls -l` in git bash shows me as the owner of all the files in the game directory. I can move and rename the files there. I'm also the owner of all the directories under `.git/objects`. What permission is git lacking?

**More info**

The structure of the path to the repo is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Foo\Bar\.git`. I previously ran `chown -R Kevin .` and `chown -R Kevin .git` inside `Bar`.

I can copy the `Bar` folder to my desktop. But copying `Bar` within `Foo` or `Foo` within `C:\Program Files (x86)` requires admin privileges.

This doesn't seem to explain what permission git needs. It should only write to the `.git` directory, right? And the error is from attempting to write files within `.git`. I can `touch` files there without any issue.

Comment: So is this Git repository entirely stored on one NTFS volume? Does it have free space? Have you tried running `chkdsk` yet?

Comment: Try to copy the local folder to a new folder, deleting the old one, and renaming the new one to the old name.

Comment: @DanielB Yes; yes, 97GB; now I have, with no problems found.

Comment: @harrymc Added more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing to `C:\Program Files (x86)` requires administrator
permissions from Windows.
To Windows, it doesn't matter that `ls -lt` in git bash shows
you as the owner of the folder, and this doesn't get you any
extra permissions from Windows on the folder.

I suggest to move the repository outside of `C:\Program Files (x86)`,
to avoid permission problems.

You may create the repository inside any folder by using
`git init` inside that folder.
You can turn any directory into a git repository this way
just by using the `git init` command.

This will avoid permission problems on the folder of the repository.

For more information see the article
[Creating Local Repositories](https://launchschool.com/books/git/read/creating_repositories).

Answer (score 0):

There could be some files with different permissions in a subdirectory.

You will need to change the directory ownership as mentioned in [this Stackoverflow Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6448326/15087622)

Comment: How applicable is that answer to Windows 10? For example, what would I use for `groupname` in `sudo chgrp -R groupname .`?

Comment: @Kevin: If you're on Win10 (assuming you mean Git for Windows, and not WSL) then you should inspect the Windows file permissions first, using icacls etc., not the emulated Unix ones...